# Consumer-Producer - MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, openmpi

I learning OpenMP and MPI and trying done every task using both of them. So now I'm working with consumer-producer problem. I've got working OpenMP version already, but I can't done properly MPI part of this problem.

I'm trying to rewrite OpenMP consumer-producer problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041030/openmp-producer-consumer-unexpected-result) with MPI instead of OpenMP. What's wrong with it? How can I improve my code to get proper result?

Now my input looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptpRB.png).

**UPDATE:** Also I tried MPI code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440922/mpi-producer-and-consumer).

My code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SIZE 5

int n = 0;
int nextin = 0;
int nextout = 0;
int count = 0;
int empty = 1;
int full = 0;
int i,j;
char buffer[SIZE];

// Put on buffer
void put(char item)
{
    buffer[nextin] = item;
    nextin = (nextin + 1) % SIZE;

    count++;
    if (count == SIZE)
        full = 1;
    if (count == 1) // buffer was empty
        empty = 0;
}

// Get from buffer
char get()
{
    char item;

    item = buffer[nextout];
    nextout = (nextout + 1) % SIZE;
    count--;
    if (count == 0) // buffer is empty
        empty = 1;
    if (count == (SIZE-1))
        // buffer was full
        full = 0;
    return item;
}


// Producer
int produced(int rankid){

    char item;
    item = 'A' + (i % 26);
    put(item);
    i++;
    if(rankid >= 10)
        printf("%d |  Produce  |  %c\n",rankid, item);
    else
        printf("%d  |  Produce  |  %c\n",rankid, item);
    printf("-------------------------\n");

    sleep(1);
    return 1;

}

// Consumer
int consumed(int rankid){
    char item;
    j++;
    item = get();

    if(item >= 'A' && item <= 'Z') {
        if(rankid >= 10)
            printf("%d |  Consume  |  %c\n",rankid, item);
        else
            printf("%d  |  Consume  |  %c\n",rankid, item);
        printf("-------------------------\n");
    }

    sleep(1);
    return 0;

    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int myrank;
    int a;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &a);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

    int count=10;
    if(myrank % 2 == 0){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            MPI_Recv(&a,1,MPI_INT,1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            if (a==0){
                a=produced(myrank); //here it returns 1
                MPI_Send(&a,1,MPI_INT,1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        a=0;
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            MPI_Send(&a,1,MPI_INT,0,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            do {
                MPI_Recv(&a,1,MPI_INT,0,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            } while (a != 1);
            a=consumed(myrank);
            n++;
        }
    }

    if(n==count){
        MPI_Finalize();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: From the help centre: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*  As currently written, this question fits that bill to a T.

Comment: I can't grasp the logic of your code, but bunning `MPI_Recv` in a loop is probably not a good idea. MPI messaging operations are atomic and for every single call to `MPI_Recv` there must be a matching call to `MPI_Send`

Comment: Edit: "consume" -> "produce" in printf in consumer function and same for producer function.